# Can I replace a single pole light switch with a GFCI switch combo?

Tags: electrical

I have an older house that has a single pole light switch in the bathroom.

it powers a single bulb vanity light above the mirror.

I would to replace it with a [switch and GFCI outlet](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=X7299-W&section=42321&minisite=10251)

there is just a black and white wire currently on single pole switch.

Is this something that can be done by either me or an electrician without costing too much?

if you need more info about my current wiring please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

No. With just what you have now it is 100% impossible. 
Right now you have a switch loop which is just a constant hot and a switched hot. Even though one wire is white there is NO neutral in this box, both are being used as hots.

You could run a new cable to this box, but you best bet BY FAR is to have a circuit run to a new GFI receptacle and just leave the existing switch alone. This is almost certainly the only code legal way to go as well. Adding a new receptacle to an existing lighting circuit in a bathroom would not meet code and will almost certainly be inconvenient due to circuit overloading.

Comment: thanx for your comment.  would I have to have new wire run all the way to the breaker box?

Comment: @Rommel109g, typically, yes. That would be the most code compliant and long term solution.